# android studio adb Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, adb, 32bit-64bit

this morning when I start doing my daily routine(opening android studio 1.5.1 in my PC - lubuntu 32 bit) I encounter an error after I try to run my application to my device. This is the android studio error:

```
Error running app: Unable to obtain debug bridge
Unable to detect adb version, adb output: /root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1: /root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

I was looking for possible solution for hours now through internet but can't find same error as this. I already try some other remedies but still no luck of solving it. Can you help me guy? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have i686 GNU/Linux (Ubuntu 14.10)

Comment: yepeey..solved the problem. I downgraded my platform-tools to r23.0.1 (which is i think not ideal, I guess?). I don't know if r23.1 is buggy or it's because of my root permissions. I copy and paste r23.0.1 which i downloaded from [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/android-sdk-platform-tools/) .. now it's working fine :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

for 32bit users... Don't update "platform-tools" to version 23.1.

foremost version you can use is 23.0.1 which you can download [here](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip)

If you are on 64bit machine and having trouble using the latest version of the plateform-tools.. check instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools).

thanks for the working link- @Tyler

Comment: Yep, I had to downgrade back to 23.0.1. I got the platform-tools folder from here and replaced the one in my Android directory. http://theandroidbeta.blogspot.com/2015/11/direct-download-android-sdk-platform-tools-rev-23.0.1-and-23.1-beta-offlne-install-november-2015.html

Comment: do you know what's the root cause of this error? Is it a bug on r23.1?

Comment: as android people already said, they are moving to 64bit environment.. now they no more support 32bit environment.

Comment: how do I install it ? please

Comment: first delete the plateform-tools folder in SDK directory then extract downloaded file in your SDK directory.

Comment: @ArnavM. as of January 2nd, that link doesn't download the proper platform-tools for me on Ubuntu 15.10. I was able to use the link provided by user Nikunj (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip) found from Yair Kukielka's answer below without problems. Maybe consider changing the link?

Comment: @ArnavM. A heads up from Google would have been nice.... I'm still procrastinating my 64-bit upgrade.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, platform-tools really caused me a lot of trouble for 32 bit sys

Comment: You need to downgrade also *build-tools to 23.0.1*

Answer (score 8):

OK. after some research found that reason for this is because

> android-sdk-linux/platform-tools content is 32-bit
>   ELF in 23.0.1 but 64-bit ELF in 23.1_rc1 and 23.1.0.  So, several
>   functions in android-studio (and I assume eclipse+ADT as well) fail
>   because of the attempt to run 64-bit executables.

This issue has already been raised [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196866)

Also, as per the official comment given by google project member **parts of the platform-tools will support 64 bit Ubuntu OS only from 23.1.0 onwards.**

> **Platform-tools 23.1.0 OR onwards will not work on Ubuntu 32-bit OS. Developer needs to upgrade Ubuntu OS to 64-bit to make it work.**

That eventually means we only have possible two workarounds now :

**1.** Stick with Platform-tool 23.0.1 as of now. and DO NOT UPGRADE platform-tools to 23.1.0 or above

**2.** Change your Ubuntu OS to 64-bit instead of 32-bit.

I hope this would help someone.

download sdk platform-tool 23.0.1 from [this link](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip)

Comment: So, Android studio updater isn't sensible to detect the OS and not ask user to upgrade the platform tools if it's 32 bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

As Arnav M. said, for Ubuntu 32bit users, stick to 23.0.1 or install a 64bit Ubuntu. For more details see this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34239600/3032209

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need to do is downgrade your platform-tool, which contains Android Debug Bridge, to lower version.
Download the platform-tool package from following link
[platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip)

Unzip the package and replace the platform-tool folder, in android-sdk folder, with the downloaded platform-tool folder.

After restarting android studio, it may ask you to upgrade platform-tool. Ignore it.