# Unable to create Debug Bridge Unable to detect adb version. Syntax error: ")" Upgrading Platform-tools 23.0.1 to 23.1.0 Linux-32 bit causes Issue

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, platform-tools

I updated Platform-tools from 23.0.1 to 23.1.0 and found some of the Android integration broke.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit with android-sdk_r24.4.1, with both android-studio (141.2456560) installed.

While executing adb command it keeps on saying below message :

> Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to
>   detect adb version, adb output:
>   /home/bhavesh/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: 1:
>   /home/bhavesh/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")"
>   unexpected

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK. after some research found that reason for this is because

> android-sdk-linux/platform-tools content is 32-bit
>   ELF in 23.0.1 but 64-bit ELF in 23.1_rc1 and 23.1.0.  So, several
>   functions in android-studio (and I assume eclipse+ADT as well) fail
>   because of the attempt to run 64-bit executables.

This issue has already been raised [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196866)

Also, as per the official comment given by google project member **parts of the platform-tools will support 64 bit Ubuntu OS only from 23.1.0 onwards.**

> **Platform-tools 23.1.0 OR onwards will not work on Ubuntu 32-bit OS. Developer needs to upgrade Ubuntu OS to 64-bit to make it work.**

That eventually means we only have possible two workarounds now :

**1.** Stick with Platform-tool 23.0.1 as of now. and DO NOT UPGRADE platform-tools to 23.1.0 or above

**2.** Change your Ubuntu OS to 64-bit instead of 32-bit.

I hope this would help someone.

download sdk platform-tool 23.0.1 from [this link](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip)

Comment: Looks liek this is not only a problem on ubuntu but for most linux kernels/distros . I got same problem and this was the same issue with my Backtrack 5 R2

Answer (score 8):

I filed that bug 8-)  If you updated to 23.1.0 already (or install a fresh android-sdk, which will insist on installing newest platform-tools), you have two solutions:

1) Get platform-tools 23.0.1 from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip  .  Go to android-sdk-linux directory, delete the "platform-tools" directory (may not be necessary) and unzip the platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip there.  SDK updater correctly shows 23.0.1 is installed next time you run it.

2) I found although qemu-2.0.0 will not run 64-bit "adb start-server", qemu-2.4.0 will!  I posted to the bug report linked above, please see my post for more info.  Long story short, I built qemu-2.4.0 source package (for Ubuntu Xxxxx Xaros -- I forget what Ubuntu 16.04's animal name is...) and installed a single extra binfmt file to enable qemu-x86_64 seamless support.  I ran "dpkg --add-architecture amd64" and "apt-get install libc6:amd64" to install base 64-bit libraries.  Done, x86-64 seamless emulation is a go!

This sounds like a recipe for the world's slowest SDK install... but actually, Java itself uses the VAST majority of CPU time running eclipse+ADT or Android Studio.  As important as the native binaries are to having a working SDK, the CPU usage of those binaries is nearly 0 (other than the phone/table emulator itself, which is needless to say quite CPU-intensive.)

Answer (score 0):

This error arrived i have in case of updated platform-tools from 23.0.1 to 23.2.0, i have solved by downloading platform-tools for 23.0.1 and start its working,
because 23.2.0 is not supported in 32 bit os version its nee 64 bit os