# Error while running an Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I recently have installed Android SDK in Linux Mint 32-bit. After that I also installed ADT plugin in Eclipse and Android SDK packages. Everything was fine, but when I completed my Android project and tried to run it on my AVD, then it was showing this error: "The connection to ADB is down". I tried almost everything to solve this. When I tried to run ADB from the terminal, it showed error that "Exec format error". I also updated my platform tools, but this problem is still present.
[Error looks like this picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWjp6.png)

Comment: Please put logcat, and code relate to error

Comment: Everything is clearly showing in the picture.

Comment: Have you tried to restart Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already an answer to your issue. Check it out:

> for 32bit users... Don't update "plateform-tools" to version 23.1.
>
> foremost version you can use is 23.0.1 which you can download here
>
> If you are on 64bit machine and having trouble using the latest
> version of the plateform-tools.. check instructions here.
>
> thanks for the working link- @Tyler
>
> FROM: [android studio adb Syntax error: ")" unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216342/android-studio-adb-syntax-error-unexpected)

Check also: [Unable to create Debug Bridge Unable to detect adb version. Syntax error: ")" Upgrading Platform-tools 23.0.1 to 23.1.0 Linux-32 bit causes Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239080/upgrading-platform-tools-23-0-1-to-23-1-0-linux-32-bit-causes-issue-unable-to-c/34239600#34239600)

Hope it help

Comment: please mark it as answer to help others with the same problem. Posts without marked answer on SO may be missed or deleted