# Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to detect adb version, adb output: /sdk/platform-tools/adb:

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, adb

How to fix out -Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to detect adb version, adb output: /home/dilip/Downloads/sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1: /home/dilip/Downloads/sdk/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
[image]

I also go to platform tool path and hit `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` command on the terminal still not able to connect device.

I also go through this link [Unable to create Debug Bridge Unable to detect adb version. Syntax error: ")" Upgrading Platform-tools 23.0.1 to 23.1.0 Linux-32 bit causes Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239080/unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-detect-adb-version-syntax-error-up)

Comment: Is your sdk updates with latest build and platform tools

Comment: yes I have updated sdk..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Got same error after update Android Studio and then Android SDK.
[SOLUTION : Downgrade /platform-tools folder]

Download this arch. : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip

- Go to your Android SDK folder
- Remove old /platform-tools
- Insert downloaded from link above

Hope this help you also