# Gradle Task,Build Failed:Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm new to android studio. Currently I'm using Boss Linux 32 bit Operating System, with java 1.8.0_151 version. And I've installed the Android Studio 3.0. Everything works fine...but when once the gradle build finishes it shows the error

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.
```

This error is headache to me, please provide me the suggestions in order to overcome this error.
I've also saw the solutions here [Android Studio 3.0 - No server to serve request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113665/android-studio-3-0-no-server-to-serve-request). But it didn't worked for me. Please give the suggestions as soon as possible. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the logs for details?

Comment: I've Checked the logs:It's Showing like: Unable to detect adb version, adb output: /home/elcot/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1: /home/elcot/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Comment: Looks like it's because of 32bit OS. See this for more details:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216342/android-studio-adb-syntax-error-unexpected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android studio adb Syntax error: ")" unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216342/android-studio-adb-syntax-error-unexpected)