# Error initializing ADB: unable to create Debug Bridge

Tags: android, error-handling

I have some problem in my Android Studio, and i use Android Studio using Linux, but i have got error with `ADB` and error like this :

> "Error initializing ADB : Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to
>   start adb server: Unable to detect adb version, output:
>   /rootAndroid/sdk/platforms-tools/adb: 1:
>   /rootAndroid/sdk/platforms-tools/adb: ###ELF#####: not found
>   /rootAndroid/sdk/platforms-tools/adb: 75:
>   rootAndroid/sdk/platforms-tools/adb: Syntax error: "(" unexpect"

And i have one question, how to start adb server ?

Because the error mentioned "Unable to start adb server".

Thanks

I hope got solved.

Comment: is your OS 32bit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34216342/1778421