# ADB fails only for Flutter but not for Android in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

It is very sttrange, but in **Android Studio** on my **Mate Ubuntu 18.04**, AMD processor when I create 'Android Project' ADB works well. But once I am creating 'Flutter' one, i have error `Error initializing ADB: Android Debug Bridge not found`.
I tried start it on Android Studio 3.2, 3.2.1...
I tried recipes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340436/error-initializing-adb-unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-start-adb-serve) - no way. 
I tried to downgrade ADB to 23.0.1 too as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216342/android-studio-adb-syntax-error-unexpected).

Here is Log:

```
ADB not found
java.lang.Throwable: ADB not found
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.adbimpl.AdbDeviceFileSystemService.start(AdbDeviceFileSystemService.java:107)
    at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.DeviceExplorerController.setup(DeviceExplorerController.java:139)
    at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.DeviceExplorerToolWindowFactory.createToolWindowContent(DeviceExplorerToolWindowFactory.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.ensureContentInitialized(ToolWindowImpl.java:571)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowManagerImpl.lambda$initToolWindow$10(ToolWindowManagerImpl.java:510)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowManagerImpl.initToolWindow(ToolWindowManagerImpl.java:513)
    at com.intellij.facet.impl.ui.FacetDependentToolWindowManager.ensureToolWindowExists(FacetDependentToolWindowManager.java:93)
    at com.intellij.facet.impl.ui.FacetDependentToolWindowManager.projectOpened(FacetDependentToolWindowManager.java:81)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.fireProjectOpened(ProjectManagerImpl.java:775)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.lambda$null$6(ProjectManagerImpl.java:391)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransactionAndWait$2(TransactionGuardImpl.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:431)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:415)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:763)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.pumpEventsForHierarchy(IdeEventQueue.java:905)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:215)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:201)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ApplicationImpl.java:579)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:109)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:318)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.run(CoreProgressManager.java:303)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.run(ProgressManager.java:192)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.loadAndOpenProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:483)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtil.openProject(ProjectUtil.java:191)
    at com.intellij.ide.RecentProjectsManagerImpl.doOpenProject(RecentProjectsManagerImpl.java:63)
    at com.intellij.ide.RecentProjectsManagerBase.doReopenLastProject(RecentProjectsManagerBase.java:677)
    at com.intellij.ide.RecentProjectsManagerBase$MyAppLifecycleListener.appStarting(RecentProjectsManagerBase.java:719)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:117)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:426)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpWaitingBuses(MessageBusImpl.java:387)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:376)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:357)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$2.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.appStarting(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.lambda$main$1(IdeaApplication.java:379)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:377)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.lambda$run$0(IdeaApplication.java:208)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:195)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:208)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:49)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:380)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: can you please show the output of flutter doctor

Comment: $ flutter doctor
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    [✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    [✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.3)
    [✓] Connected device (1 available)
    
    • No issues found!

Comment: i even reinstalled to ubuntu 18.04 (as in my office) - no way!

Comment: adb in concole (via ALT-F12) works well. But Device File Explorer shows `Error initializing blah-blah` and i can not debug and see files in emulators and device...

Answer (score 6):

That problem makes me slow down alot. Like you @Valery Kulikov , I tried those links u mentioned and many others. Finally, I found the solution in Chinese website https://blog.csdn.net/net_wolf/article/details/88971642 but that don't solve the whole. Ok, I will tell u the solution that works for me. In Android Studio, File->Project Structure->Modules->YourProjectName_android->Dependencies->Module SDK: (select API as your Android Emulator) and click Apply and OK. Then, restart Android Studio. I hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when I fresh installed Flutter SDK and following steps helped me out.

1. Go to platform-tools folder in your Android SDK, make sure adb files aren't nested into another folder. If nested, move all files to top platform-tools folder. Platform-tool folder shouldn't be nested and it should have adb inside it
2. Install SDK tools from your SDK manager (if hidden, uncheck Hide Obsolete Packages)
3. Execute `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and accept the licenses
4. Execute `flutter doctor -v`, it should show [✓] in Android ToolChain